# Regular Expression for image?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have to upload images into DB using file up-loader. I have used the given below code, but it is not working. If I upload any pdf or doc file that also inserting into DB and the error message also displaying. I want to stop insertion if the file is not an image format. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

ASPX :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload1" runat="server" ForeColor="#999999" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*jpeg,gif,png" ControlToValidate="PhotoUpload1" ForeColor="Red" 
ValidationExpression=".*\.([gG][iI][fF]|[jJ][pP][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|[bB][mM][pP])$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: you could use `(?i)` modifier to do a case insensitive match.

Comment: `"(?i).*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$"`

Answer (score 5):

This should work for jpg, png, gif and png.

**UPDATED**

```
/.*\.(gif|jpe?g|bmp|png)$/igm
```

You can check how it works [here](http://regexr.com/3a1j7)

Comment: `[e?]` matches `e` or `?`

Comment: @AvinashRaj did this to match both jpg and jpeg.

Comment: your regex matches `jp?g` also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try [alternation](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) "|" notation. And only list allowed file extensions (whitelist) like jpg,png.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload1" runat="server" ForeColor="#999999" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*jpeg,gif,png" ControlToValidate="PhotoUpload1" ForeColor="Red" 
ValidationExpression="(.*png$)|(.*jpg$)|(.*jpeg$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Asp.Net validation need to be [validated on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064256/41782) too.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Note that there might be ServerSideValidation which evaluated to false.
       if (!Page.IsValid)  
         return;

       // Insert DB code here.
    }
```

Comment: I want insert only image file into DB. These answers are showing error message if the selected file is not a image format while clicking insert button, but the file also inserting into db

Comment: The given below code is used to insert data into DB. QA_Form2TableAdapters.tbl_QA_InstallationTableAdapter qa; 
qa =new QA_Form2TableAdapters.tbl_QA_InstallationTableAdapter();  qa.InsertAll(ddlState.Text, ddlDistrict.Text,PhotoUpload1.FileBytes);